# Does stopping a timer end the goroutine?

Tags: go, memory, concurrency, timer, goroutine

Does a simple goroutine like the below code that is stopped by stopping a timer become clean? Or stay in memory until the end of the program?

```
go func() {
    <-timer1.C //Will stop before firing.
    fmt.Println("Timer 1 fired")
}()
```

Comment: It's incorrect to think of anything as "killing" a go routine. They exit naturally when the flow of execution reaches the end of the method, they're not "killed" by any external process.

Comment: Thanks to @meagar Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the channel is closed, the Go routine will exit. If the channel remains open but nothing is ever sent over it, then the Go routine will "hang" forever, until the program exits.

If `timer1` is a `time.Timer`, then `Stop` will *not* close the channel, as explained in the documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/time#Timer.Stop